Kernel of homomorphism on direct sum of abelian groups
Let $G$ be an abelian group and suppose $f : G \oplus G \to G$ is a surjective non-trivial homomorphism. Is it always true that the kernel of $f$ is isomorphic to $G$?
If we replace $G$ by finite dimensional vector spaces over a field, then I believe this is true just by looking at the rank-nullity theorem. But I don't think this is the case for abelian groups, although I haven't thought of a counter-example...

It is not necessarily true for vector spaces of infinite dimension (no reason to ask for "infinite field"; rank-nullity holds over any field). You can have $G\oplus G\cong G$ for abelian groups.

Yes you're right, I was only thinking of finite dimensional vector spaces when I was writing up my question.

It is not true even for finite abelian groups. Fix a prime $p$, and let $G=C_{p^2}\oplus C_{p}$. Then $G\oplus G\cong C_{p^2}\oplus C_{p^2}\oplus C_p\oplus C_p$, and there is a surjection onto $G$ by mapping one $C_{p^2}$ to the $C_{p^2}$ factor of $G$, sending the second $C_{p^2}$ factor onto the $C_p$ summand, and the two $C_p$ summands to the identity. The kernel is isomorphic to $(C_p)^3\not\cong G$.
